# Keep user logged in between browser sessions

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the sample code for my project. It contains two forms on a single page.

The first form contains username and a textbox, when I enter the username and click the login button the user's name should be displayed and the logout form should be displayed.

How do I ensure that the user will remain logged in once the browser window is closed?

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login Page</title>
<head>
<script>
   function set(x)
{
    document.getElementById(x).value="";
}
  </script>
<script>
      function showDiv(e) 
   {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

     if (e==1) 
        {
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
{
if (divs[i].id=="hidevar1")divs[i].style.visibility="visible"; 
else if (divs[i].id=="hidevar2")divs[i].style.visibility="hidden"; 
}
      } 
   else    {
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
{
if (divs[i].id=="hidevar1")divs[i].style.visibility="hidden"; 
else if (divs[i].id=="hidevar2") {
    divs[i].style.visibility="visible"; 
    }
}
}
        }

       function put()
  {
var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
currentTime=new Date();
    if(currentTime.getHours()<12)
   var y = "Good Morning ";
    else if(currentTime.getHours()<17)
   var y = "Good Afternoon ";
    else 
   var y = "Good Evening ";
   document.getElementById("devin").innerHTML = "Hello " + x + " " + y;
   }
</script>
   <script>
</script>
<script>
function search()
{
    var dic = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var str="http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&q=";
    var www=str+dic;
    window.open(www);   
}
</script>
</head>
        <body>
     <div id="devin">
       </div>
<div id="hidevar1" style="visibility: visible;">

         <form name="frm1" method="post"  >//Login form
          User Name : <input type="text" id="fname" value="Enter name here"   onfocus="set(this.id)" >
     </form>
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="showDiv(2);put();">
</div>

<div id="hidevar2" style="visibility: hidden;">

      <form name="frm2">//logout form
      <script>
</script><br/>
<input type="submit" value="logout">
<br>
    <br>

       </form>
</div>
    <br><br>
         <input type="text" name="url1" id="url" />
    <input type="submit" value="google"onclick="search();" />
         </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You don't have a password, just a username? Go set the username cookie with your prefered lifetime and get the cookie onload server sided and then proceed imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use spring, spring-security provides [remember me services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) which would let you be logged in across browsers or sessions.

Other option is to use [Apache shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) if you find spring-security too complex for your application.

Comment: anybody share code for javascript cookies to view my last visited page after close and again open my browser.